# Spring Batch Boot - Write data to multiple places based on the Status Code while reading data from CSV?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am developing ***Spring Boot Batch*** example. In this example, reading data from the `CSV` and based on status code values (like `SUCCESS`, `REJECT`, `PENDING`, `COMPLETED`) I want to write it into 4 different places (MySQL, XML, Postgres, Salesforce DB) while writing ?. I can see we can pass only 1 type of List of `Customers` to `CompositeItemWriter` method. How can I pass 4 different `Customer` List to `CompositeItemWriter` ?

Here I could think of using `CompositeItemProcessor` and `CompositeItemWriter`. In the `CompositeItemProcessor` I will take the decision of separating the records in all these processors and now question is how can I passed the `SUCCESS` to `MYSQL`, `REJECT` to `XML`, `PENDING` to `Postgres` and `COMPLETED` to `Salesforce DB`?

```
@Bean
public CompositeItemProcessor<Customer, Customer> compositeItemProcessor() throws Exception{
    List<ItemProcessor<Customer, Customer>> delegates = new ArrayList<>();
    delegates.add(new FilteringSuccessProcessor());
    delegates.add(new FilteringRejectProcessor());
    delegates.add(new FilteringPendingProcessor());
    delegates.add(new FilteringCompletedProcessor());

    CompositeItemProcessor<Customer, Customer> processor = new CompositeItemProcessor<>();
    processor.setDelegates(delegates);
    processor.afterPropertiesSet();

    return processor;
}
```

**FilteringSuccessProcessor.java**

Like this I've created processor all the Status Codes and

```
public class FilteringSuccessProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Customer, Customer> {

    @Override
    public Customer process(Customer item) throws Exception {
        if(item.getStatus == "SUCCESS"){
            return item;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Now my question is - How can we pass 4 different data results to CompositeItemWriter to write it into 4 different places?

I though of using `CustomerClassifier` as well, but how to pass four different list to same writer ?

Any guidance ? This is very interesting use case, but look like critical to implement.

Comment: I second the answer by @slimane, the `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter` is the way to go. A similar answer with an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53388876/5019386

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use classifierCompositeItemWriter and define your routing policy inside it:

it is an ItemWriter that will take care of writing to different places base on your status using a Classifier.

```
    @Bean
    public ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<Item> classifierCompositeItemWriter(ItemWriter<Item> POSTGRESWriter, ItemWriter<Item> SQLWiter) {
        ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<Item> classifierCompositeItemWriter = new ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<>();
        classifierCompositeItemWriter.setClassifier((Classifier<Item, ItemWriter<? super Item>>) item-> {
            if (item.getStatus("Success")) {
                return POSTGRESWriter;
            } else {
                return SQLWiter;
            }
        });
        return classifierCompositeItemWriter;
    }
```

you can configure your Step as Follow:

```
    @Bean
    public Step process() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("dataExtraprocessctionStep")
                .<Item, Item>chunk(1)
                .reader(itemReader())
                .writer(classifierCompositeItemWriter(POSTGRESWriter(), SQLWriter()))
                .stream(POSTGRESWriter())
                .stream(SQLWriter())
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: I am not clear on the return POSTGRESWriter. Can we return instance of ItemWriter<Item> from ClassifierCompositeItemWriter. Could you please elaborate your answer ?

Comment: I second this answer, the `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter` is the way to go. A similar answer with an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53388876/5019386