# Spring Batch read from db write to different files by records

Tags: file, resources, spring-batch, writer

I am trying to read from db with records like one header and many related details, then I have to output to different file by the composite key of headers.
For example,
table countries(header) with columns: country_id, name, area
table country_stats(detail) with columns: country_id, year, population, gdp

how to assgin every header+details to different file?
Using ClassifierCompositeItemWriter with delegating to a list of FlatFileItemWriter?
If it could be used, how I assign resource to every FlatFileItemWriter at runtime?

Please give me some hints.

Comment: How many stats records are there for each country? In other words, is the relation country -> stats one-to-one or one-to-many? This is key to correctly answer your question.

Comment: the number of detail records for each header data is not fixed. It is one-to-many relationship. MultiResourceItemWriter might not fit this scenario.

Comment: You can find an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67604628/spring-batch-classifiercompositeitemwriter-footer-not-getting-called/67635289#67635289